# how to Automatic Detect data from database in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys I want to auto detect price and show in textbox from database in visual basic 2008 and this is my code but it is not working. any suggestion thanks

table name : transporter_profile
Column name: price

```
Private Sub load_transportation()
    Dim sqlquery As String
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
    tb_test.Clear()
    sqlquery = "SELECT price FROM transporter_profile ORDER BY 
    price"

    ConnectmyDB()
    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery
    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader

    If myData.HasRows = False Then

    Else
        While myData.Read()
            tb_test.Text = myData.GetString("price")

        End While
    End If
    DisconnectDatabase()
End Sub
```

Comment: It is never sufficient to say "it is not working".  An acceptable question always includes a FULL and CLEAR explanation of EXACTLY what happens and EXACTLY how that differs from your expectation.  If there are compilation errors or run-time exceptions, tell us where and provide the error message(s).  If the code runs but doesn't behave as expected then describe in details the expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: there is no error and it can run but do not detect the data from database it show empty the box...

Comment: It doesn't just show an empty box. Even if that's the ned result, there's plenty that happens to get there and that's what you need to find out for yourself before you post here.  You need to learn how to debug your code.  You need to have a clear expectation of what is going to happen at every step and then compare that to what actually did happen.  At the very least, that will allow you to provide all the relevant information here.  If you don't know how to debug, start learning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: You should also put a bit more thought into your code.  For one thing, what's the point of that `If` statement?  More importantly though, if you are retrieving every record from your table and setting the `Text` of a `TextBox` from each one in turn, what exactly do you expect the result to be?  Each value will replace the previous one so, at best, you're going to see the last value only.  If that's what you want then why retrieve the rest at all?  If that's not what you want then your code is not an implementation of what you actually want, which debugging would have revealed.

Answer (score 1):

try with this source code :

```
  Private Sub load_transportation()
    Dim sqlquery As String
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
    tb_test.Items.Clear()
    sqlquery = "SELECT price FROM transporter_profile ORDER BY price"

    ConnectmyDB()
    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery
    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader

    If myData.HasRows = False Then

    Else
        While myData.Read()
            tb_test.Items.Add(myData.GetDouble("price"))
        End While
    End If
    DisconnectDatabase()
  End Sub
```

Comment: A `TextBox` doesn;t have an `Items` property and if you think the OP ought to use a `ComboBox` then you'd need to at least say so, but probably ought to actually check whether it's appropriate first.

Comment: @NewCoder, I checked your user page, you NEVER accept the answers that work for you, please do!